# Раздача ip по wifi роутером DLINK DSL_2640NRU

Tags: ip, dsl, wifi, lan

Почему мой планшет получает адрес 192.168.106.79, а не 192.168.1.79 ?В настройках Сеть-Вайфай нет таких настроек, есть настройки тут>`Сеть-Соедининие-LAN-Главная-Настройки IP IP-адрес: 192.168.1.1Маска: 255.255.255.0Сеть-Соедининие-LAN-DHCP серверНачальный IP: 192.168.1.2Конечный IP: 192.168.1.255`Что еще глянуть?PS устройства в сети всегда разные - кто-то с телефоном придет, кто-то с планшетом, ноутбуком, надо чтобы всем выдавался айпи из одной под сети![alt text][1]![alt text][2]![alt text][3]![alt text][4]![alt text][5]![alt text][6]![alt text][7]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipT4V.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0wum.png  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHCh4.png  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8De4U.png  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXqiG.png  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu0NK.png  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg19a.png

Comment: я на планшете подсоединился именно к той сети, которую отдает мой роутер и в станционном списке на роутере я вижу по мак-адресу что он соеденился благополучно.Если только у этого роутера нет двух разных DHCP отдельно для LAN и отдельно для WiFi, так бывает? не пойму как это узнать

Comment: Дайте скрины своих настроек там, где LAN DHCP.

Comment: скрины:http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen55.pnghttp://minicrm.ru/trash/screen56.png http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen57.png http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen58.png http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen59.png http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen60.png http://minicrm.ru/trash/screen61.png забавно телефон с вторым андроидом получил айпи нормальный 192.168.1.4 а вот планшет с 3 андроидом получает не нормальный айпи - из другой под сети, а еще вчера macbook pro получал айпи из другой подсети

Comment: прошивка не менялась, т.е. 1.0.0когда народ из офиса уйдет попробую обновить,а на счет статических айпи - нет, тут в андроиде его никак нельзя указать, если в подключаемой сети включен WPS, как я понимаю

Answer (score 1):

А вы уверены, что получаете сетевые настройки от своего DHCP-сервера? Похоже, что в вашей вести несколько DHCP-серверов, с разными настойками.

Answer (score 0):

Статику в андроиде можно указать всегда в `Беспроводные сети-настройки wifi`, где добавить сеть, а там можно задать dhcp/static. Предварительно нажмите `забыть сеть`.